# For loop stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop

My for loop is stuck in an infinite loop and I can’t figure out why. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

jData is an array extracted from a text file. The images are currently stored in a comma separated string and this loop should extract them and display them one by one.

```js
 for( var i = 0 ; i < jData.length ; i++ ){ //runs loop to populate container.
     //console.log("array images contains " + jData[i].imgs);

                   
                    if (jData[i].imgs){
                        var sImages = jData[i].imgs;
                        var aImages = sImages.split(',');

                        for( var i = 0 ; i < aImages.length; i++) {
                            sPropertyTemplate = sPropertyTemplate.replace( "{{images"+i+"}}" , aImages[i] );
                            console.log(aImages[i]);
       break;
                        }
                    }

                    var sPropertyTemplate = sProperty;
                    sPropertyTemplate = sPropertyTemplate.replace( "{{id}}" , jData[i].sUniqueId );
                    sPropertyTemplate = sPropertyTemplate.replace( "{{address}}" , jData[i].sAddress );
                    sPropertyTemplate = sPropertyTemplate.replace( "{{type}}" , jData[i].sType );
                    sPropertyTemplate = sPropertyTemplate.replace( "{{price}}" , jData[i].iPrice );
                    sPropertyTemplate = sPropertyTemplate.replace( "{{locLat}}" , jData[i].lat );
                    sPropertyTemplate = sPropertyTemplate.replace( "{{LocLng}}" , jData[i].lng );
```

Comment: You are reusing `i` in the second loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same variable `i` in both, the inner and outer loop. So you will always overwrite its value it should have in the outer for-loop.

What you should do, use a different variable for the inner loop, such as `j`:

```
for( var j = 0 ; j < aImages.length; j++) {
    sPropertyTemplate = sPropertyTemplate.replace( "{{images"+j+"}}" , aImages[j] );
    console.log(aImages[j]);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Yes realised that myself today, Thanks :).